# Can't open executable in WinDbg

Tags: windbg

I've got an executable I want to debug in WinDbg. The executable requires some files as arguments, and I'm passing those in via WinDbg's Open Executable window. The problem is, when I navigate to the executable I want to debug and select it (again via the Open Executable window), I get an error message from the program saying it can't find the files I passed in as arguments. This is despite the fact that I've verified those files are in the same folder as the executable, and I've set the Start Directory (in the Open Executable window) to the directory that contains the executable and necessary argument files. Am I misunderstanding how WinDbg attaches to a process? See the screenshot below for a setup of my folder and how I've configured the Open Executable Window.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest debugging the code the tries to access these files and see what makes it fail. I think you can use WinDbg for that.

Comment: quit exploring and start typing :) windbg foobar.exe -te x:\\tabtabtab\file -ts y:\tabtabtab\file2.xml-.enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong path to the Start directory. The way I described is the proper way to attach WinDbg to an executable that requires arguments.

Comment: You can't attach an executable to WinDbg - it's the opposite way round. And there is a difference in memory management whether you run an executable under the debugger (like you) and attaching a debugger to an already running process, so the word "attach" does not fit in here.

Comment: Sorry for nit-picking, but when it comes to debugging, it's better to be precise.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer.